# Can we override adb environment variables from terminal?

Tags: android, adb

ADB has following environment variables in their docs.
What is the purpose of providing them in docs. Can we override their default values from terminal ? If so how?

```
environment variables:
 $ADB_TRACE
     comma-separated list of debug info to log:
     all,adb,sockets,packets,rwx,usb,sync,sysdeps,transport,jdwp
 $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS         colon-separated list of keys (files or directories)
 $ANDROID_SERIAL          serial number to connect to (see -s)
 $ANDROID_LOG_TAGS        tags to be used by logcat (see logcat --help)
 $ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT max emulator scan port (default 5585, 16 emus)
 $ADB_MDNS_AUTO_CONNECT   comma-separated list of mdns services to allow auto-connect (default adb-tls-connect)
```

I am trying to set as shown in [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables)
I have tried the same on windows PowerShell and macOS terminal without any effect.

for widows powershell I tried

```
set ANDROID_VERBOSE=radio;adb logcat
```

for macos terminal I tried

```
export ANDROID_VERBOSE=radio;adb logcat
```

But I don't find any difference in output

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of listing them in the documentation is simply to tell people who need to use them that they exist. I don't know Powershell, but the correct macOS syntax is:

```
export ANDROID_VERBOSE=radio
adb logcat
```

or:

```
ANDROID_VERBOSE=radio adb logcat
```

You can use either, according to your taste.